# How to access /cygdrive/c in nginx?

Tags: nginx, winginx

I am trying with Nginx under windows; it requires the file located in the /cygdrive/c.

If I installed cygwin, then everything is file. I am wondering if I can use Nginx without cygwin? How to specify the file in the location like c:\nginx

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use a nginx without Cygwin.  See http://wiki.nginx.org/Install#Official_Win32_Binaries

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code:

```
location / {

 root  /cygdrive/d/www/; # '/cygdrive/d/' equal to  'D:\' in Nginx under Cygwin
            index  index.html index.htm;            
}
```

If we want to set `D:\www\newsB\` for `http://www.#yours.com/newsA/`, then we better use `alias` or `rewrite` directive of Nginx, something like:

```
location /newsA/ {

alias /cygdrive/d/www/newsB/;

}
```